# Hide HTML table rows if outputField is null or 0

Tags: visualforce, email-template, html

I am creating a confirmation email to be sent when a new `Orders__c` is created via an external form. These are not related objects so an `<apex:repeat>` solution is not viable. There are 50+ fields that may be shown and I would like to avoid having a bunch of blank rows.

My ideal solution would be the equivalent of adding `rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.Item1__c == null, false, true)}"` to the `<tr>` tag, but I don't reckon that's an option in static HTML.

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate relatedToType="Orders__c" subject="Order Received: {!relatedTo.Name}" replyTo="noreply@redacted.com">

        <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
            <html>
                <body>

                <p>Thank you for submitting your order. It has been received and will be processed shortly. You will receive notification when the order has shipped.</p>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                <center>
                    <p>Order Summary</p>
                </center>
                <p>Order:               {!relatedTo.Name}</p>
                <p>Order Received:      {!relatedTo.Submitted__c}</p>
                <p>Date Needed By:      {!relatedTo.Date_Needed_By__c}</p>
                    <br/>
                <p>Site Code:           {!relatedTo.Site_Code__c}</p>
                <p>TCA Name:            {!relatedTo.TCA_Name__c}</p>
                <p>TCA Email:           {!relatedTo.TCA_Email__c}</p>
                <p>TCA Phone:           {!relatedTo.TCA_Phone__c}</p>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>       

                <p>Total Items Ordered: <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Total_Items_Ordered__c}" /></p>
                <p>Notes: <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Notes__c}" /></p>

                    <table border="1">                      

                        <tr> //HIDE THIS IF Item1__c == 0
                            <td>Item1: </td> //HIDE THIS IF Item1__c == 0
                            <td colspan="2"> <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Item1__c}" /> </td> //HIDE THIS IF Item1__c == 0
                        </tr> //HIDE THIS IF Item1__c == 0
                        <tr> //HIDE THIS IF Item2__c == 0
                            <td>Item2: </td> //HIDE THIS IF Item2__c == 0 
                            <td colspan="2"> <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Item2__c}" /> </td> //HIDE THIS IF Item2__c == 0
                        </tr> //HIDE THIS IF Item2__c == 0

                        /* long list of items*/


                    </table>

                </body>
            </html>
        </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: why not wrap the `<tr>` with `apex:outputPanel` and use rendered= there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `display:none;` in a `style` attribute to hide elements.

```
<table style="{!IF(relatedTo.Item1__c == null, 'display: none;', '')}">
```

Don't forget, if you want to also check for `0` values, you need your criterion to be:

```
OR(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Item1__c), relatedTo.Item1__c == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Can I tack `style="{!IF...}"` to the `<tr>` tag? It looks like this method would result in a disjointed table for each individual line item.

Comment: @jatuttle0 Yes, you can implement it on any given element.

Comment: `<tr style="{!IF(!relatedTo.Item1__c == null || relatedTo.Item1__c == 0, 'display: none;', '')}">`  is coming back with `Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean, received Number 
`

Comment: @jatuttle0 Please edit your question with what you tried and your error text *at the bottom*. Why did you negate your null check?

Comment: Turns out I made a whoopsie and had `{!IF(!relatedTo...)}`. Works now that I took out the extra `!`

Comment: @jatuttle0 Yeah, that makes sense. Better to use `OR`, `NOT`, and `ISBLANK` functions to make the logic more clear.